# Use SHA512 to hash a password to encrypt data

Tags: c#, encryption

I have a C# application in which I sometimes have to encrypt some data (XML file). Basically, the problem is I cannot store any keys on a server, or directly in the code, as `.NET` apps can be easily disassembled with for example `dotPeek`.

So basically my app would encrypt XML file and save it on disk, and then would be able to decrypt it.

I came up with an idea to ask for a passphrase every time a user wants to encrypt/decrypt the data. This passphrase would be hashed with SHA512 and the resulting bytes would be used as a key to encrypt the data. Then if the user wants to decrypt the file, they are asked for a passphrase again and this passphrase is used to decrypt the file (it may fail if the user enters a wrong passphrase).

So my first question would be: Is it actually a good idea?

My second question is about the implementation. I have hashing, serialization, deserialization, but I don't know which encryption algorithm should I use (I guess not RSA as the data to be encrypted would be really long) and then can I pass the passphrase as a key to this algorithm?

Comment: You do know you just moved where the secret is to the left an inch.  Someone can just look at your app to see what the name of the file is and what the password and/or encryption method is.  As is, this is very broad for SO.

Comment: @Disaffected1070452 How would that be? The password would only be used to en/decrypt, the OP never said it would be stored

Comment: Hashed password would be stored, not the real password

Answer (score 2):

You've stumbled upon the idea of a Key Derivation Function (KDF).  What you're suggesting is, with a few differences, an excellent idea and one used often.  The small-ish issue is that SHA-512 alone is not a good KDF.  I recommend you read about PBKDF2 (in .NET, the implementation is called `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`).  Password hashes like bcrypt and argon2 are also very viable choices.

In regards to your question regarding the encryption algorithm, AES is currently considered the "standard" symmetric encryption algorithm.  There are many other viable options however.  Just ensure you aren't using DES or Triple-DES, they're dated algorithms.  Also ensure you're using a secure block mode.  GCM is arguably the "best".

Comment: Thanks for the input. I actually had an enlightenment and I thought about using `ProtectedData.Protect/Unprotect` as its more convenient than typing a passphrase every time. What do you think?

Comment: Personally I would use your original solution.  `ProtectedData` has some undesirable nuances...

Comment: Do you have some resources about those nuances? Cuz this is a project for my university professor and he is keen on not typing the password